# Traer datos de una tabla de mongo a express

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

quiero traer la información de una tabla.
Este es el codigo del models
Registro.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose
const RegistroSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: { type: String, require: true },
    edad: { type: String, require: true },
    correo: { type: String, require: true },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('persona', RegistroSchema)
```

Y esta es la logica

```
router.get('/Personas', async(req, res) => {
    await Registro.find() 
})
```

No se que poner en la función para traer los datos de mongodb

Comment: `{campo: valor}` esto es un *filter* según la documentación de mongoDB

Comment: o sea seria así?  await Registro.find({
     nombre: nombre,   edad: edad, correo: correo
    })

Comment: sip, pero el `valor` o en tu caso `nombre` tendría que ser algo que recibas por parámmetro, seria algo `const {nombre} = req.body;` y luego haces `await Registro.find({ nombre: nombre})`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás tratando de aplicar `await` sobre un método que [no devuelve una Promesa](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises). De la documentación de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html):

> Las consultas de Mongoose no son Promesas. Tienen una función `.then()` para `co` y `async / await` por conveniencia. Sin embargo, a diferencia de las Promesas, llamar a `.then()` de una consulta puede ejecutar la consulta varias veces.

Dicho esto, necesitas obtener una Promesa si deseas asignar el resultado de `find()` a una variable. Como estás usando `async / await`, para trabajar con una Promesa, debes envolver el código en un bloque `try / catch`, ya que una Promesa puede ser resuelta o rechazada.

Todos los objetos de tipo [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html) de Mongoose (`find()`, `findOne()`, `findById()`, etc.) proveen un método llamado [`exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-exec) que ejecuta la consulta y devuelve efectivamente una Promesa. Por lo tanto, debes encadenar el método `exec()` a tu consulta, de la siguiente forma:

```
Registro.find().exec()
```

De esta manera, ya podrás trabajar con el resultado devuelto por dicha Promesa y almacenarlo en una variable para ser enviado al cliente o para procesarlo antes de enviarlo, según lo que necesites hacer.

Un ejemplo del código sería el siguiente:

```js
router.get('/Personas', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        let message = 'Registros encontrados';
        let registros await Registro.find().exec();
        console.log(registros); // puede tener registros o un array vacío
        if(!registros.length) {
            message = 'No existen registros';
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
          message,
          registros
        });
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
        let message = 'Error en la consulta';
        return res.status(500).json({
            message
        });
    }
});
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**P.D.**

Mongo **no usa tablas**, usa **colecciones** y almacena **documentos**. Evita hablar de tablas cuando te refieres a datos almacenados en MongoDB.

Comment: muchas gracias ya entendi a que te referias, pero tengo una duda como hago para imprimir esto en un html, digamos yo uso .hbs este es mi html <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre</td>
    </tr>
    {{#each data}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{nombre}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre</td>
    </tr>
</table>